# Automate colouring excel tables with a script

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a pipeline of scripts - mostly implemented in bash, R and python to get a .csv file.

Output of pipeline/input for new process: X number of .csv files with standardised tables.

Output of new process: one excel file with X number sheets (from X .csv files). Those results must be filtrated and excel cells must be assigned to a specific colour based on numeric thresholds.

Goal: Is there any way to use a script that can be run in a UNIX terminal to process it automatically without opening excel for every file?

My first idea was to use VBA excel code but I need some guidance on how to do it with a script in the terminal. A python solution would be optimal if such exists.

Comment: Please, specify if you want an VBA solution (you'll need to open the file for that), a Python solution, a Unix solution or what. Use the proper tags. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to colour your Excel cells, based on their values, you might use conditional formatting, as you can learn from this screenshot:

[image: Conditional formatting screenshot]